# How to write this nested Linq To Xml query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi I am writing an app for a medical study 
they will type in 
the gender, the age, and some other values which will be calculated to a ResultValue

now I have an XML file which holds some information about the result in combination
of Age, Gender and the ResultValues  and I would like to print out the description of the TestResult (in case in which group the proband belong)
One thing to note is that I have to deal with value ranges this means the actual value lies between the low part and the high part...
I have three groups...
OK hier is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <Result>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Description>You belong to Group 1</Description>
        <Genders>
            <Gender type="female">
                <Ages>
                    <Age low="18" high="24">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="19"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="25" high="34">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="20"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="35" high="44">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="21"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="45" high="54">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="22"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="55" high="64">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="23"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="65" high="110">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="24"/>
                    </Age>
                </Ages>
            </Gender>
            <Gender type="male">
                <Ages>
                    <Age low="18" high="24">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="19"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="25" high="34">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="20"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="35" high="44">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="21"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="45" high="54">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="22"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="55" high="64">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="23"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="65" high="110">
                        <ResultValue low="0" high="24"/>
                    </Age>
                </Ages>
            </Gender>
        </Genders>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Description>You belong to Group 2</Description>
        <Genders>
            <Gender type="female">
                <Ages>
                    <Age low="18" high="24">
                        <ResultValue low="19" high="24"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="25" high="34">
                        <ResultValue low="20" high="25"/>

                    </Age>
                    <Age low="35" high="44">
                        <ResultValue low="21" high="26"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="45" high="54">
                        <ResultValue low="22" high="27"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="55" high="64">
                        <ResultValue low="23" high="28"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="65" high="110">
                        <ResultValue low="24" high="29"/>
                    </Age>
                </Ages>
            </Gender>
            <Gender type="male">
                <Ages>
                    <Age low="18" high="24">
                        <ResultValue low="19" high="24"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="25" high="34">
                        <ResultValue low="20" high="25"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="35" high="44">
                        <ResultValue low="21" high="26"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="45" high="54">
                        <ResultValue low="22" high="27"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="55" high="64">
                        <ResultValue low="23" high="28"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="65" high="110">
                        <ResultValue low="24" high="29"/>
                    </Age>
                </Ages>
            </Gender>
        </Genders>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Description>You belong to group 3</Description>
        <Genders>
            <Gender type="female">
                <Ages>
                    <Age low="18" high="24">
                        <ResultValue low="24" high="29"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="25" high="34">
                        <ResultValue low="25" high="30"/>

                    </Age>
                    <Age low="35" high="44">
                        <ResultValue low="26" high="31"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="45" high="54">
                        <ResultValue low="27" high="32"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="55" high="64">
                        <ResultValue low="28" high="33"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="65" high="110">
                        <ResultValue low="29" high="34"/>
                    </Age>
                </Ages>
            </Gender>
            <Gender type="male">
                <Ages>
                    <Age low="18" high="24">
                        <ResultValue low="24" high="29"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="25" high="34">
                        <ResultValue low="25" high="30"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="35" high="44">
                        <ResultValue low="26" high="31"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="45" high="54">
                        <ResultValue low="27" high="32"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="55" high="64">
                        <ResultValue low="28" high="33"/>
                    </Age>
                    <Age low="65" high="110">
                        <ResultValue low="29" high="34"/>
                    </Age>
                </Ages>
            </Gender>
        </Genders>   
    </Result>
```

What would look my linq to xml query like if I have

gender="female"

age=29

ResultValue=17

this proband would certainly belong to Group 1 and I would like to 
print out the matching Description...

But I am banging my head to get this working...

I am looking for a solution in c#...
Any help would be great!!!

Comment: Are you looking for a VB.Net LINQ to XML query or a C# one.  Very different answers.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! I am looking for a c# solution...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
XElement myElement = XElement.Parse(xmlstring);

int resultValue = 17;
int age = 26;
string genderValue = "female";

IEnumerable<string> query =
    myElement.Descendants("ResultValue")
        .Where(rv => ((int)rv.Attribute("low")) <= resultValue)
        .Where(rv => ((int)rv.Attribute("high")) >= resultValue)
        .Where(rv => rv.Ancestors("Age")
            .Any(a => ((int) a.Attribute("low")) <= age && ((int) a.Attribute("high")) >= age)
        )
       .Where(rv => ((string)rv.Ancestors("Gender").Single().Attribute("type")) == genderValue)
       .Select(rv => rv.Ancestors("Result").Single().Element("Description").Value);

    foreach (string x in query)
        Console.WriteLine(x);
```

The idea is that you can imagine a row-column shape where each row is a ResultValue.  Each result value has a single parent of Age, a single parent of Gender, an a single parent of Result.

ResultValue.Low
ResultValue.High
Age.Low
Age.High
Gender.Type
Result.Description

In fact, one can project the above xml into that shape:

```
        var query2 = myElement.Descendants("ResultValue")
            .Select(rv => new 
            {
                ResultValue = rv,
                Age = rv.Ancestors("Age"),
                Gender = rv.Ancestors("Gender"),
                Result = rv.Ancestors("Result")
            })
            .Select(x => new XElement("Data",
            new XAttribute("ResultValue.Low", (int)x.ResultValue.Attribute("low")),
            new XAttribute("ResultValue.High", (int)x.ResultValue.Attribute("high")),
            new XAttribute("Age.Low", (int)x.Age.Attributes("low").Single()),
            new XAttribute("Age.High", (int)x.Age.Attributes("high").Single()),
            new XAttribute("Gender.Type", (string) x.Gender.Attributes("type").Single()),
            new XAttribute("Result.Description", (string) x.Result.Elements("Description").Single())
            ));
        foreach (XElement x in query2)
            Console.WriteLine(x);
```